# How can I install Windows 8 while dual-booting Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows-8

I have a new Dell laptop which has inbuilt Ubuntu OS in it, I would like to install Windows 8 alongside Ubuntu, that is, without removing Ubuntu.

Comment: This is a question regarding Windows not Ubuntu, ask it on Superuser.com here it's off topic.

Comment: well you will have to reinstall grub when you are done installing Windows, so that you can boot from Ubuntu again...

Comment: @adi that's wrong. If windows is preinstalled, then only the problem comes. Otherwise you can boot any version of ubuntu as long as GRUB identifies windows loader.

Comment: My bad, I remember reading somewhere about win8 not working alongside older versions then ubuntu 12.10, but now as I searched it cannot find anything,probably I read something else and I remembered it as my own version,sorry if I created any confusion

Comment: A lot of what's asked here is on-topic. The Windows 8 installer won't resize Ubuntu's partitions, so the user has to do that manually. And like previous versions of Windows, Windows 8 will want to be installed to primary partitions; assuming the disk has an "ms-dos" style partition table, it may be necessary to move Ubuntu partitions into a extended partition. We can at least close this as a dupe of a general question about preparing an Ubuntu-only system for side-by-side Windows installation. If there are preparatory steps specific to preparing for Windows 8, then this is its own question.

Comment: @EliahKagan And which question would that be?

Answer (score -1):

Without any problem run Windows 8 installation, and when you are asked for drive to what you want to install it, simply create new partition, give some value for it and select new created partition to install on. If this not work, boot in Ubuntu, click dash home from launcher and type in search box: disk utility. When you open it, select your hard drive from left side, and create partition which will be NTFS formated and give some value to it. Then reboot, run Windows 8 installation, and select that new partition created.

Comment: The Windows 8 installer can't shrink Ubuntu's partitions, so as you anticipated, that won't work unless there's already unpartitioned space. But the same problem will happen in Disks in Ubuntu (which "Disk Utility" is now called). Disks (and "Disk Utility" before it) can't create partitions if there's no space to create them. You have to boot from an Ubuntu or similar live CD/DVD/USB to shrink the existing partitions. Then it is still better to simply *leave unpartitioned space* for the Windows 8 installed to create partitions the way it wants them. (Windows 7 makes *2*, W8 probably does too.)